# 2D Vector Initialization: Initialization setting weird length

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating a 10x10 grid for a battleship game. I am using vector template of a 2D array, and am running into trouble when I am initializing it. When I initialize the 2D vector I am trying to set each space of the 10x10 vector to `' '`, but for some reason I am getting each coordinate initialized to 10 spaces instead of 1 space.

**board.hpp**

```
#ifndef BOARD_HPP
#define BOARD_HPP
#include "ship.hpp"
#include <vector>

class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char> > coordinate;
    Ship carrier;
    Ship battleship;
    Ship floater;
    Ship submarine;
    Ship destroyer;
public:
    Board();
    char *coord(int row, int column);
};

#endif // BOARD_HPP
```

**board.cpp**

```
#include "board.hpp"

Board::Board() : coordinate(std::vector<std::vector<char> >(10, std::vector<char>(10, ' '))), carrier('C',5), battleship('B',4), floater('F',3), submarine('S',3), destroyer('D',2)
{
    //Constructor
}
char *Board::coord(int row, int column)
{
    return &coordinate[row][column];
}
```

Here is the game file the boards feed into:

**game.hpp**

```
#ifndef GAME_HPP
#define GAME_HPP

#include "board.hpp"

class Game
{
private:
    Board *playerBoard;
    Board *compBoard;
    Board *compBoardHidden;
public:
    Game(Board *player_board, Board *comp_board, Board *comp_board_hidden);
    void display();
};

#endif // GAME_HPP
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include "game.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Game::Game(Board *player_board, Board *comp_board, Board *comp_board_hidden) : playerBoard(player_board), compBoard(comp_board), compBoardHidden(comp_board_hidden)
{
    //Constructor
}
void Game::display()
{
    std::cout << "             | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|             | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|" <<std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "          ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+          ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n           " << char(65+i) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,0) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,1) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,2) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,3) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,4) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,5) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,6) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,7) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,8) << " | " << playerBoard->coord(i,9) << " |           " << char(65+i) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,0) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,1) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,2) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,3) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,4) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,5) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,6) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,7) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,8) << " | " << compBoard->coord(i,9) << " |" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `' '` to initialize the vector and you are wondering why it is filled with spaces? Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: Well sort of, I am trying to initialize the vector to have one space per each coordinate. However when I reference a coordinate in my vector such as    coordinate[0][0] it contains not only one character ' ' but 10 ' ' characters

Comment: Oooh. Well, I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed46ead6639d5c88). Please create a [mcve].

Comment: One second will set it up in the Coliru ordeal.

Comment: Ok I have shared it and it does reproduce with the error I am referring to. I havent used the Coliru Viewer before so here is what it gave me.This file can be also found using the Coliru command line: cat /Archive2/77/2303fe28a81497/main.cpp

Comment: @Rakete1111 Hey if you get some time and could look at this I would appreciate it. I have the link to the Coliru viewer and am pretty stumped about what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, but I can't access the link. Try to reduce your example so that you can post it here in full while still reproducing the error. I for one reduced it too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector is completely fine, the only problem is when you print a single element.

Your code has undefined behavior because you are printing a char array which isn't null-terminated. `std::cout` has an overload for `operator<<` for `char*`, i.e. strings, and that overload is taken. You need to dereference it to print out the actual character.

Why are you even using pointers? If you someone on the outside has to be able to modify it, just use a reference.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, and I am relatively new to pointers so I using some projects like this to help me learn it better. I previously had used a 2D vector and it worked fine, but may have rebuilt it this time with an unforeseen error. Thanks for the help.